# How can one identify the fan model and other fan specs within Linux?

Tags: linux, fan

I know I could disassemble my laptop to find this information, but I was curious if I could find it in the /dev or /proc directory, or from a shell command. There was no fan information in /proc/acpi and lshw returned nothing useful. Any ideas?

Comment: You'd be more likely to find that information in the repair manual for that laptop model. If you give the make and model, We could point you to the repair manual.

Comment: There are three different fans available for the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot identify the fan model via software

A fan is typically connected through a 3 pin cable, and reports back only the fan speed to the motherboard

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the Linux version I can't know for sure but you might try `dmidecode -t 27` if you're running Debian.

In short, this says: "give me information about my cooling device" (27 is code for cooling decide for dmidecode).  However, I should mention that I'm making an assumption that you want information on the CPU cooling decide and not some other tertiary fan information.  Here is a good [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/how-to-get-hardware-information-on-linux-using-dmidecode-command/) describing dmidecode a little more in detail.

Comment: It appears that there is an "OEM-specific Information" field returned for `dmidecode -t 27` but it always (or at least in every example I've seen) is 0x00000000.  I tried!